# Add value to a Set inside a Map

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, set, hashset

How can I add a value to a HashSet inside a HashMap?

```
Map<String, Set<String>> myMap;
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by `I haven't found an answer targeting the general concept.`

Comment: I downvoted it because after your comment `Try searching for an answer here on SO. The answers are made to fit the exact problems OPs have faced`. I did exactly the same and found an answer that exactly answers your quesiton : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15797446/java-given-a-map-string-set-how-do-i-fill-the-set-given-a-string. So when you say you dind't find an answer that meets your requirement, you need to elaborate what requirement it doesn't meet in comparison to other answers.

Comment: This question is being [discussed on MetaSO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290988/3001761).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### The answer is not short, but simple:

1. `get` the Set
2. make sure it's not `null`!
   *If it's null `put` it in the map first.*
3. alter the Set
   *Changes to the Set are automatically reflected in the Map.*

#### le code:

```
Set<String> theSet = myMap.get(aKey);
if (theSet == null) {
    theSet = new HashSet<String>();
    myMap.put(aKey, theSet);
}
theSet.add(value);
```

---

#### Best used like this:

```
// ...

    Map<String, Set<String>> myMap = new HashMap<String, Set<String>>();
    addValue("myValue", "myKey", myMap);

// ...


private void addValue(String value, String key, Map<String, Set<String>> map) {
    Set<String> set = map.get(key);
    if (set == null) {
        set = new HashSet<String>();
        map.put(key, set);
    }
    set.add(value);
}
```

Comment: You only have to put the set back in if it was null. Otherwise, the put is redundant.